# Why is converting words into singular from plural in a for loop taking so long (Python 3)?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, nlp, textblob

This is my code to read text from a CSV file and convert all the words in a column of it into singular form from plural:

```
import pandas as pd
from textblob import TextBlob as tb
data = pd.read_csv(r'path\to\data.csv')

for i in range(len(data)):
    blob = tb(data['word'][i])
    singular = blob.words.singularize()  # This makes singular a list
    data['word'][i] = ''.join(singular)  # Converting the list back to a string
```

But this code has been running for minutes now (and possibly keep running for hours, if I don't stop it?)! Why is that? When I checked for few words individually, the conversion happens instantly - doesn't take any time at all. There are only 1060 rows (words to convert) in the file.

**EDIT:** It finished running in about 10-12 minutes.

Here's some sample data:

Input:

```
word
development
investment
funds
slow
company
commit
pay
claim
finances
customers
claimed
insurance
comment
rapid
bureaucratic
affairs
reports
policyholders
detailed
```

Output:

```
word
development
investment
fund
slow
company
commit
pay
claim
finance
customer
claimed
insurance
comment
rapid
bureaucratic
affair
report
policyholder
detailed
```

Comment: You are iterating over a data frame. Performance will be terrible..

Comment: @RafaelC Oh! I didn't know that! Why is that so? And what should I use to store the file if not a dataframe? I find multidimensional lists a pain in the a** to work with in Python - its not as intuitive as, say, in C.

Comment: Because you're constantly shuffling your data across the Python/C threshold, which is expensive. Also, `.words` is a pretty complex operation; `.singularize` might be the fastest thing in you have in your code.

Comment: Can you provide some sample input/output ? Also, you are doing `data['word'][I]` and probably getting a warning that you're changing a copy and not your df ?

Comment: @RafaelC Yes, it did throw that warning! I edited the question to include a portion of the input and output.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: from textblob import Word

In [3]: s = pd.read_csv('text', squeeze=True, memory_map=True)

In [4]: type(s)
Out[4]: pandas.core.series.Series

In [5]: s = s.apply(lambda w: Word(w).singularize())

In [6]: s
Out[6]:
0      development
1       investment
2             fund
3             slow
4          company
5           commit
6              pay
7            claim
8          finance
9         customer
10         claimed
11       insurance
12         comment
13           rapid
14    bureaucratic
15          affair
16          report
17    policyholder
18        detailed
Name: word, dtype: object
```

I use `squeeze` here to let `read_csv` return a Series instead of a DataFrame because the word file only has one column. In addition `memory_map` can be used if the word file is large.

Can you test the performance with your data?